# Javascript for a submit button

Tags: javascript

I want a script for Javascript where I want to display a particular record when a particular button will be clicked.

So, here is my requirement:

Here is a particular record where it governs through a 3 stage workflow process(Submit to assessor,reviewer and practice auditor). In this record there are 50 questions and when the user completes the assessment by attempting all 50 questions he'll click save and review button which is present by default at the bottom of the page.

So, i want when the user clicks the Save and Review button, after that an automatically the "Submit to reviewer" button will appear. Same operation I want to perform for assessor and practice auditor.

Can anyone please explain the script which I've to write to accomplish this scenario?

Comment: I charge reasonable rates to do this for you

Answer (score 0):

You just need to hide the button you wish to show, and reappear it when needed like this:

```
if(document.getElementById("element").click()){
   document.getElementById("elemenet2").style.visibility = "visible";
}
```

This is the easiest way using pure java script.